# How debug signed app with intellij idea?

Tags: android, debugging, google-api

I try to use Google Calendar API in my Android App.
 My problem is - I need every time create signed APK and load it to device manually. 
 I'm looking for solution how I can debug signed application?

ps I use I intellij idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution:

1. Create signed APK
2. Load APK to device
3. Install APK
4. Run App
5. Without uninstall app run project in debug mode from IDE
6. Profit!

Comment: I have Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES]

Comment: Oh, sorry. I know solution - use use 2 different keystore files. Place nested keystore file (which signed apk) to "user/..../.android" folder (idea take it as default)

Comment: As I've found out it works only for debug keystore. For release keystore you just launch app from device and then attach debugger to it's process from IDEA. But you need <application android:debuggable="true"> in AndroidManifest.xml or nothing will work

Comment: Thanks for comment. I don't work with release keystore yet.  offtopic note: nice to meet countryman on SO.